# Why is amplitude of x-rays scattered by crystal is less than the amplitude of rays incident on crystal?

Tags: x-ray-crystallography

Why is amplitude of scattered rays less than the amplitude of rays incident on crystal?

Also what will be the situation in case of free electrons?

Comment: How could the amplitude of the scattered rays possibly be *greater* than the amplitude of the incident rays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [The amplitude of an x-ray is](http://www.school-for-champions.com/science/x-ray_characteristics.htm#.WRloAcYlHIU) equivalent to its intensity or brightness. Just like a bright visible sunlight can cause a burn, so too can an intense x-ray burn the skin.

X-rays in an incident beam ideally are all parallel and the intensity of the beam  is concentrated in a crossectional area perpendicular to the direction of motion . once it hits a target three things can happen:

Part of it goes through without interacting, already diminishing the straight intensity.

Part of it will scatter elastically, thus opening the crossectional area and diminishing the intensity.

Part of it may interact , raising energy levels in the atoms. Relaxation of the excited states will have a 4 pi distribution , thus again diminishing the forward beam intensity.